# Understanding arrow functions - why does this not work and this does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrow-functions

I am trying to convert all of my older code to use arrow functions...

The following works:

```
$p_worklist.mouseover (()=> {
   closemenues();
   console.log ("Show Worklist");
 $div_worklistmenu.show();
});
```

However this does not

```
$p_worklist.mouseover =()=> {
   closemenues();
   console.log ("Show Worklist");
 $div_worklistmenu.show();
};
```

The difference is that the first function wraps the body in parens while the second does not but rather replaces the first paren with equals sign and eliminates the second one.

Trying to learn...
Thanks

Comment: The first one is a function call.

Comment: @tkausl no it isn't. oops yes it is

Comment: OK sorry about the bogus comment. The difference really doesn't have anything to do with arrow functions.

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrow functions. The same difference can be seen when doing `mouseover = function(){ … }` instead of `mouseover( function(){ … } )`

Comment: In the first example you **use** the `mouseover` method of jQuery. In the second one you **override** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the arrow function, but your usage of the `mouseover` attribute to set an event listener.

In JQuery (which, given your use of `$`, I'm assuming you're using), `mouseover` is a *function* that takes another *function* as an argument. So, you would pass an anonymous arrow function exactly as you do.

In vanilla JavaScript, however, the `mouseover` attribute is a pointer to the function to be called as an event listener.

If you're using JQ:

```js
$('selector').mouseover(() => {
  // ...
});
```

If you're using JS:

```js
element.mouseover = event => {
  // ...
}
```

---

Of course, you can override the JQuery method yourself by using the setter, but that's *probably* not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is **calling** `$p_worklist.mouseover`, and passing in a function. Jquery will then do whatever internal code it needs to do to set up the event listener, and when a mouseover happens, it will call the function you gave it.

The second one is **assigning** to `$p_worklist.mouseover`, thus overwriting what used to be there with the function you created. No other code is run, and no event listeners are set up.

Jquery's api expects you to call it, so option 1 is the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

In Your first example You invoke mouseover method, hovewer in next exaple You just overwrite that method and You don't invoke it

Answer (score 1):

`mouseover()` is a jQuery method. Like all jQuery event-handling methods, it takes the handler function as a parameter, so you have to call the method.

When you assign to `$p_worklist.mouseover`, you're replacing the method with a new function, not calling the method. That's not how you bind event handlers in jQuery.

You're confusing the jQuery method calls with DOM `onXXX` properties, where you write something like

```
element.onmouseover = ()=> {
    closemenues();
    console.log ("Show Worklist");
    $div_worklistmenu.show();
};
```